# Angular 7: prevent escaping of HTML tags inside a string variable passed to child component through data binding

Tags: javascript, html, angular

In my Angular 7 app I have a simple home component using one-way data binding on a string variable (i.e. I pass a variable to a child component using @Input with the `[text]="'Some text'"` syntax).

I would like to include html tags such as links in the variable and render it in the child component but the code below fails because of the anchor tag. How to fix this?

home.component.ts:

```
{ Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  template: '
    <app-card [text]="'Some text and a link: <a href="https://stackoverflow.com" target="_blank">link</a>'">
    </app-card>
  ',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent {}
```

card.component.ts:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-card',
  template: '
    <div class="bla bla">
      <p>{{text}}</p>
    </div>
  ',
  styleUrls: ['./card.component.css']
})
export class CardComponent {
  @Input() text: string;
}
```

Edit: I wrote 'templateUrl' but that was wrong, I mean 'template'. Let me add that my real card template is more complicated than the div shown here, and I actually use templateUrl in both components as follows:

```
templateUrl: './about.component.html', //in app component

templateUrl: './card.component.html',  //in card component
```

Comment: have you tryed like this `[text]="{key: 'sdbjvbjhbvsdbv'}"`?

Comment: i'm not giving you down votes

Comment: @Abhishek Thanks, your proposed solution gives [Object object] or so

Comment: have you try `text.key` for get value?

Comment: Thanks but I do not think your approach will help, cause I think the problem is writing a string with all the quotes as the following in my html template: 
"'Some text and a link: <a href="https://stackoverflow.com"  target="_blank">link</a>'"

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I actually found how to do it. First, I needed to use innerHTML for the

element:

```
<p innerHTML={{text}}>{{text}}</p>
```

Second, some funky syntax. In the parent Home component notice that href and target attributes do not need quotes:

```
<app-card [text]="'Some text and a link: <a href=https://stackoverflow.com target=_blank>link</a>'">
</app-card>
```

Edit: Other users point to DOMSanitizer, but that forces me to write the text in the typescript part of the app component, not in the template part. 
As @John Velasquez says in another answer, this "solution is more likely a constant that cannot be changed anymore its more likely a one-way binding."

Comment: Works for me. Do you by any chance know how to display a mat icon there, like <mat-icon>cloud_download<mat-icon>. It shows the "cloud_download" name for me, but not the icon, even if while I use it in component.html it works fine

Comment: In your previous comment you forgot the slash in the closing tag: </mat-icon>. Does it only show cloud_download or also the tags "mat-icon"?

Comment: Is the inner `{{ text }}` truly necessary?  This works for me:
`<p innerHTML={{text}}></p>`

Answer (score 15):

[This is by far the best and cleanest way to do it](https://medium.com/@AAlakkad/angular-2-display-html-without-sanitizing-filtering-17499024b079)

**Angular 2: Display HTML without sanitizing/filtering**

1) Create new file to hold the pipe pipes/keep-html.pipe.ts:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

    @Pipe({ name: 'keepHtml', pure: false })

export class EscapeHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
  }

  transform(content) {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(content);
  }
}
```

2) Add an import statement in your app.module.ts:

```
import { EscapeHtmlPipe } from './pipes/keep-html.pipe';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    EscapeHtmlPipe
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

3) Finally use that pipe in your template:

```
<div [innerHTML]="post.body | keepHtml"></div>
```

Kudos to [Ammar Alakka](https://medium.com/@AAlakkad) for sharing this solution .

Comment: This works well! However, how can we apply pipe to content within the div tags? Something like: `<div> {{myVar | keepHtml}} </div>`. All other Angular pipes such as the `price` pipe work that way. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

use **DomSanitizer** to bypass html

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-card',
  templateUrl: '
    <p [innerHtml]="result"></p>
  ',
  styleUrls: ['./card.component.css']
})
export class CardComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() text: string;

  result: any;
  constructor(private sanitized: DomSanitizer) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.result = this.sanitized.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.text);
  }
}
```

see stackblitz for complete guide
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-w6qys9

Comment: That works after fixing <hello name=.. to <hello innerHtml=.. 
What do you think about my simple solution below? Yours is probably more elegant

Comment: Actually my issue with your solution is that I actually want to write the text with link in the parent template, not in the typescript part. That's because in my real example I use templateUrl with html files for both components.

Comment: @aless80 its better if you do it this way if your `text` can be dynamically change at runtime, your solution is more likely a constant that cannot be changed anymore its more likely a one-way binding. but if it works for you its okay.

Answer (score 1):

for links you can use

```
<a [href]="text">Angular Docs</a>
```

If you want to pass a big html block, you'll need [innerHtml]
https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#property-binding-or-interpolation

See : https://angular.io/guide/ajs-quick-reference

Answer (score 1):

Try using DomSanitizer, bellow I give example where I used it for sanitizing a URL for use in iframe src property, but it also has a function to sanitize HTML:

```
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
// ... then 
constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
}
// ... then (I used it with url, but it has an html sanitizer)
this.path = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.sanitizer.sanitize(SecurityContext.URL, 'SOME_URL'));
// ... then in HTML
<iframe [src]="path"></iframe>
```